# Beautiful soup.find error after several findings

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I try to edit a html-file with beautiful soup. After a few problems getting startet i thought i finaly had it done. But now i get a random error in one of my loops which i really don´t understand. I implemented e few checks to maybe find the error, but it didn´t help me. I suspect some kind of "overload" but could´nt figure out how i can fix it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_file = '****' #html file location

with open(html_file, "r") as file_content:
    data = file_content.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

x = 2
y = 1
print(soup.find(id="2-1"))
old_line = soup.find(id=f"{x}-{y}").parent
print(old_line)

x = 1
while x < 10:
    y = 1
    while y < 6:
        print(f"x={x}")
        print(f"y={y}")
        print(f"{x}-{y}")

        print(soup.find("td", id=f"{x}-{y}"))
        old_line = soup.find("td", id=f"{x}-{y}").parent
        new_line = soup.find("td", id=f"{x+1}-{y}")
        new_line['id'] = f"{x}-{y}"
        old_line.find("td", id=f"{x}-{y}").replace_with(new_line)
        print(old_line)
        y += 1
    x += 1
```

ouput:

```
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="2-1"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<tr>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="2-1"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="2-2"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
</tr>
x=1
y=1
1-1
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-1"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<tr>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-1"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-2"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
</tr>
x=1
y=2
1-2
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-2"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<tr>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-1"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-2"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
</tr>
x=1
y=3
1-3
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-3"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<tr>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-3"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-4"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
</tr>
x=1
y=4
1-4
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-4"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<tr>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-3"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-4"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
</tr>
x=1
y=5
1-5
<td id="1-5"><span class="player-text">scrotiemcboogerballs</span> greift an<br/>Er verursacht <span class="red-text">12345678</span> Schaden</td>
<tr style="border:0px black none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
<td class="grafik-spalte">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-1"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-2"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-3"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
<td class="kleine-tabelle" id="1-4"><img height="40" src="tumbleweed.gif" width="40"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td id="1-5"><span class="enemy-text">Biosellerie</span> greift an<br/>Er verursacht <span class="red-text">5743841</span> Schaden</td>
</tr>
x=2
y=1
2-1
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "****", line 25, in <module>
    old_line = soup.find("td", id=f"{x}-{y}").parent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

any ideas? please forgive me if my mistake is simple, coding is just a hobby and i pretty much have no idea. Thank you!

Comment: There's no point in using a loop like `while x < 10:` if all you ever do is increment `x` by the same amount at the end of each iteration. Just use a for loop and a range. Can you provide a [mcve]? The follow article should come in handy: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: thank you for your input! i think i found my misstake. i edited id 2-1 in the loop it does and changed it´s id to 1-1. that is the reason why i found id 2-1 at the start, but not after the first editing loop. with this in mind i re-wrote the code and it works.

with the loops you mentioned. i thought about a "for x in range(len())" loop but chose the while loop. what exactly is the difference? the effekt is the same, isn´t it?

thanks for the debugging page!